# Retrieve Columns from SQL Database Table Based on User Input in HTML Form

Tags: php, mysql, database

I apologize if this has been covered before. I looked at all of the suggestions and nothing seems to fit what I need here.

In any event, I am trying to develop an auto parts bank where the following information is stored in a table called "auto_parts":

- Distributor
- Address
- City
- State
- Zip
- Phone Number
- SKU
- Part
- New or Used
- Year
- Make / Model
- Price

[The table looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLd4Y.png)

I want customers to be able to submit a form that asks them the following questions:

City, State, Part, New or Used, Year, and Make / Model,

which would query my database and output **all of the information** on the table column that meets the previous criteria:

**Query Output:**

- Distributor
- Address
- City
- State
- Zip
- Phone Number
- SKU
- Part
- New or Used
- Price

Here is an abbreviated version of my form:

```
<form action="parts_query.php" method="get">
<h2 align="center">Find Auto Part</h2>
<strong>City:</strong> 
<br />
<input type="text" name="City" value="City" required>
<br />
<strong>State:</strong> 
<br />
<select name="State" size="1" required><option selected="selected">Choose One:
<option>AL
<option>AK
<option>AZ
<option>AR
<option>CA
<option>...
</select>
<br />
<strong>Select Part:</strong>
<br />
<select name="Part" size="1" required><option selected="selected">Choose One:
<option>A Pillar
<option>A/C Compressor
<option>A/C Compressor Clutch Only
<option>A/C Condenser
<option>A/C Condenser Fan
<option>A/C Control Computer
<option>A/C Evaporator
<option>A/C Evaporator Housing only
<option>A/C Heater Control (see also Radio or TV Screen)
<option>A/C Hose
<option>Accelerator Parts
<option>Adaptive Cruise Projector
<option>...
</select>
<br />
<strong>New or Used?</strong>
<br />
<select name="New_Used" size="1"><option selected="selected">Choose One:
<option>New
<option>Used
</select>

<br />
<strong>Vehicle Year:</strong> 
<br />  
<select name="Year" required><option selected="selected">Choose One:
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
</select>
<br />

<strong>Vehicle Make / Model:</strong><br /> 
<select name="Make_Model" required><option selected="selected">Choose One:
<option>AMC Ambassador
<option>AMC American
<option>AMC AMX
<option>...
</select>
<br />
<br />
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have tried numerous variations of queries to search my database table for the above information submitted via my form, then output all relevant information (as outlined above) to an HTML table, but nothing seems to work. I am still pretty new to working with databases and again I apologize if my question seems redundant or overly broad.

I don't remember how parts_query.php originally looked because I've been changing it a lot, but what I have now looks like this:

```
    <?php
//Connecting to sql db.
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","autoparts_bank");

$query = "SELECT * FROM auto_parts WHERE City = [] AND Part = [] AND Year = [] AND Make_Model = []"
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr>
<td>" . $row['Distributor'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['City'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['State'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Zip'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Phone'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Part'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['New_Used'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>
</tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; 

mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
?>

<?php
//Connecting to sql db.
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","autoparts_bank");
//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `auto_parts` (`Distributor`, `Address`, `City`, `State`, `Zip`, `Phone_No`, `SKU`, `Part`, `New_Used`, `Year`, `Make_Model`, `Price`) 
VALUES ('$_POST[Distributor]', '$_POST[Address]', '$_POST[City]', '$_POST[State]', '$_POST[Zip]', '$_POST[Phone_No]', '$_POST[SKU]', '$_POST[Part]', '$_POST[New_Used]', '$_POST[Year]', '$_POST[Make_Model]', '$_POST[Price]')");
?>
```

Comment: Show your attempts to query the DB that has failed already for you. Also you are using `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: It is not clear if you re having a problem writing the query, or to design the all application itself. Check this link , it may help : http://www.sitepoint.com/sql-server-php/

Comment: based upon the screenshot of the db table I think you are going to end up with a lot of redundancy in the db. You might want to consider having separate tables for distributor, cities and then for the auto_parts themselves and use keys to link between

Comment: You can't mix drivers `mysql_query` doesn't work with `mysqli_` (nor does `mysql_close`. `mysqli` is the right driver to use but you need to use it everwhere. Don't use user provided data in your SQL. You need to process each user provided piece of data and dynamically build your query.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused... I'm using XAMPP on my computer and trying to learn to work with SQL databases. This seemed like a relatively simple project I could tweak and modify to work for other scenarios down the line. Now I'm not sure...

Comment: `mysql_` are deprecated functions you want to be using `mysqli`. See this for a long write up on it http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php. Pretty much `If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is strongly recommended that you use the mysqli extension instead.` So you should never use a function starting with `mysql_` unless you wrote it.

Comment: So in your current attempt does the user have to fill out all fields or are fields optional?

Comment: I'm using options with predefined input for most of the elements; they just use a drop-down and pick the year, the make / model of their vehicle and the part. The only thing they manually type is their city; everything else is predefined.

Comment: For your cities, this might be useful? http://www.farinspace.com/us-cities-and-state-sql-dump/

Comment: Thanks. That looks helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To return submitted form data to an external page, simply retrieve the [$POST or $GET form](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) variables and then pass them as [parameters in SQL query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp):

```
<?php

// RETRIEVE FORM DATA (consider using $POST array to avoid url show and character limit)
$city = $_GET["City"];
$state = $_GET["State"];
$part = $_GET["Part"];
$new_used = $_GET["New_Used"];
$year = $_GET["Year"];
$make_model = $_GET["Make_Model"];

// DATABASE CONNECTION 
// (consider saving credentials below in external .php file and required in this script)
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "autoparts_bank";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// QUERY PREPARATION AND EXECUTION
$query = "SELECT * FROM auto_parts 
          WHERE City = ? AND Part = ? AND Year = ? AND Make_Model = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

if ($stmt) { 

    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $city, $part, $year, $make_model);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    echo "<table>";

    // LOOP THROUGH RESULTS
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
        echo "<tr>
               <td>" . $row['Distributor'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['City'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['State'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['Zip'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['Phone'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['Part'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['New_Used'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>
             </tr>";  
    }

    echo "</table>"; 

    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();

} else {
    echo "query failed: ".$conn->error; 
}

// CLOSE CONNECTION
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: I tried this but get the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\webdev\auto-parts-db\parts_query.php on line 23

Comment: See edit. I missed a closing semicolon after SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks. It's still generating an error, but this time it's Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\webdev\auto-parts-db\parts_query.php on line 31

Comment: SQL query has an error. I now wrap the while loop in an if/then logic with error message. See what MySQL complains about. I suspect it's because `Year` is a varchar()? If so, the bind params should be all S's (strings): `bind_param('ssss')`.

Comment: Yes year is varchar, as is everything else in the table except for price which is a decimal. I tried the 'ssss' and I'm still getting a fetch error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\webdev\auto-parts-db\parts_query.php on line 34

Comment: Hmmmm...see edit. I move from OOP (`->fetch_assoc`) to procedural (`mysqli_fetch_assoc`).

Comment: lol Well it was downgraded to a warning: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webdev\auto-parts-db\parts_query.php on line 35... I really appreciate your help. I just need to do more reading :)

Comment: I suspect it could be your empty/unset $_GET variables. You should not be just running parts_query.php but filling out form and pressing submit where html form calls this page.